# Sbt-Native-Packager Control file inconsistent name to .deb created

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, debian, sbt-native-packager

I'm not very familiar with Scala or sbt-native-packager but have a scala project where we create a debian.  What I've noticed is that the name of the .deb created is correct, but the control file isn't - is there a way to change this?

Versions:

```
Play: 2.2.3 (also tried with 2.2.6)

Sbt-Native-Packager: 0.7.6
```

In plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.6")
```

This is what I've got (minus sensitive information):

Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
.settings(scalaVersion := "2.10.4")
.settings(DebPackageSettings.packageSettings(appName, appVersion, baseDirectory): _*)
```

In DebPackageSettings:

```
def packageSettings(appName: String , appVersion: String, baseDirectory: SettingKey[java.io.File]): Seq[sbt.Setting[_]] = {

  val baseName = "prefix-project-name"
  val appPackageArchitecture = "all"

  Seq(
      name in Debian := "%s".format(baseName),
      version in Debian := "%s".format(appVersion),
      packageDescription in Linux := "something",
      packageSummary in Linux := "something",
      target in Debian <<= (Keys.target) apply ((t) => t / (baseName + "_" + appVersion + "_" + appPackageArchitecture))
  )
 ...
```

The control file (in DEBIAN/control) that gets created:

```
Source: project-name
Package: project-name
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
...
```

The .deb created: ***prefix-project-name_version_all.deb***

Am I missing something? I've looked through the sbt-native-packager docs and googled for some answers but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `name in Debian` only affects the `.deb` file-name, not the package name in the control file. For this you should use `packageName`. The plugin is quite confusing regarding its name spaces and inheritance.

After a bit of testing, I found the following should make it work:

```
name        in Linux := baseName,
packageName in Linux := baseName,
```

If you use `in Debian`, you get a some hybrid product where half of the names are from main scope name, the other half from debian scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Actually figured out a different way using normalizedName and changing the imports.  (Formatting is off, so adding this as an answer)

Comment: Yes, the scopes where things are derived from is not always intuitive. We try to work hard on this, but SBT is sometimes a bit tricky. Also you are using a very old version of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work - but what is the preferred/right way?

The imports:

```
 import sbt._
 import sbt.Keys._
 import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
 import NativePackagerKeys._
```

The added line:

```
  normalizedName in Debian := "%s".format(baseName),
```

Not sure what is preferable though!